read UDP response with BASH script
I have a simple UDP server written in PYTHON3 (the one as example in Python doc).
On the other side I want to send commands to this server with a very simple bash script :
exec 3<>/dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8080
echo -e "doSomeThing" >&3

I do receive the command on server side : good. But When the command has finished I would like to answer something like "It worked ok" or "Something went bad" according to the success or failure of the execution of the command.
So I did (server side in handle function of UDPHandler class (see Python doc))
returnCode=cmde.upper()+"\n"+"exit:OK" //if command is OK;)
returnCodeBytes=bytes(returnCode, 'utf-8')
socket.sendto(returnCodeBytes, self.client_address)

Now on client side (in my bash script) I want to read the answer and ideally put it in a variable.
If I write : read -u 3 v1 v2 v3, the script stays stuck in this read command (I tried various variations of read within a While loop etc.=> same); same if I do cat <&3
What's wrong ? How should I do ?

readreads lines with a line ending but your message has none. Try Exit:OK\n

Nop : read stays stuck :( with EOT, ETX, EM, FS, NUL as well
